# How do I connect my git folder to a gitlab group project?

Tags: git, gitlab, project-management, collaboration

```
git config --global user.name "Frederik Walther Liberoth Christoffersen"
git config --global user.email "frederik210103@gmail.com"
cd project-quagle
git init
git remote add origin git@gitlab.com:niggotandchangot/project-quagle.git
touch README.md
git add .
git commit -m "Added README"
```

When I type in the above lines, git works as usually, but when I finally push I get an error.

```
git push -u origin master
```

**Error:**

> ssh: connect to host gitlab.com port 22: Connection refused fatal:
>   Could not read from remote repository. Please make sure you have the
>   correct access rights and the repository exists.

The weird thing about this is that it on  gitlab.com says that I have Owner Acces to both the group and the project that I want to push to.

**What is happening and what can I do to fix it? And can you possibly send me a tutorial on how to do this properly? (Can't find one)**

***Thanks.***

Comment: Have you generated a pair of SSH keys and added the public one to your Gitlab account? See https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/

Comment: Thanks for answering but it seems on my profile settings on gitlab.com that the ssh-key that I added via the help of Git GUI is registered. However I will try to check it again with the command that Baklap4 suggested me to use when I get acces to my computer again. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

When pushing through SSH you'll need a SSH Key.

One can be generated with the following command:

```
ssh-keygen -t rsa -C "your_email@example.com"
```

Then hit enter to save your key to the default location.
Then you may enter a passphrase, and repeat that passphrase again. This passphrase has to be filled in everytime you want to push.

You then have to upload your public ssh key to gitlab so you can push your branch. This can be done under https://gitlab.com/profile/keys

To check your public ssh key use the following command: `cat $HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub`
Copy this output to the text area at above link.

You may now push through ssh to gitlab.

A link to the offical docs can be found here: https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ssh/

Comment: Did this help you out @frederik